# Recommended usability testing firms to do international testing with?

Tags: resources, usability-testing

We want to do a baseline usability study in Italy and Russia next year. Can anyone recommend a good consulting agency that would be able to help us in either country? Or just a good international consulting agency in general?

We would need help with the recruit, moderating the study and translations but we would do the analysis. Ideally we would like to observe the sessions remotely.

Answer (score 1):

[UXalliance](http://www.uxalliance.com/) has members all around the world. Perhaps you will be able to find a firm that will suit your needs.